# When did Tyrion Lannister say "That's what I do, I drink and I know things"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I remember he said it at least twice: In season 5 in the room with Missandei and Grey Worm and then again in season 6.

I made a bet with someone who claimed Tyrion said it earlier as well, in season 1 when visiting Winterfell.

Who is correct?

Comment: What a great premise to a question, I believe he's only said it twice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

He said it once in [Season 6 Episode 2, Home](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4077554/quotes):

> Tyrion Lannister: Dragons do not do well in captivity.
>
> Missandei: How do you know this?
>
> Tyrion Lannister: That's what I do. I drink and I know things.

It can be viewed here:

He didn't say it in Season 1 at all.

I also went through Season 5 Transcripts and he didn't say it in it either but he said something remotely similar in S05E10:

> Daario/Jorah: Can you fight?
>
> Tyrion: I have fought. I don't claim to be a great warrior.
>
> Daario/Jorah: Are you good on a horse?
>
> Tyrion: Middling.
>
> Daario/Jorah: **So mainly you talk**.
>
> Tyrion: **And drink. I've survived so far**.

Comment: A quick look through the scripts reveals he doesn't say it in Season 1 or Season 5.

Comment: So they both lose the bet. @BinyaminRegev Send me the money!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder That's what I was going through. He didn't say it

Comment: Where are the transcripts can be found? Btw, The winner of the bet needs to go to the set and ask Emilia Clark on a date, the loosers stay home.

Comment: @BinyaminRegev [You can find the transcripts here](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=game-of-thrones)